# How to synchronize database in INSERT INTO query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

Here is my query.

```
INSERT INTO compare_moodle 
            (userid, 
             username, 
             firstname, 
             lastname, 
             courseid, 
             coursename) 
SELECT mdl_user.id, 
       mdl_user.username, 
       mdl_user.firstname, 
       mdl_user.lastname, 
       mdl_course.id, 
       mdl_course.fullname 
FROM   mdl_user 
       JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra 
         ON mdl_user.id = ra.userid 
       JOIN mdl_role r 
         ON ra.roleid = r.id 
            AND r.id = 5 
       JOIN mdl_context c 
         ON ra.contextid = c.id 
       JOIN mdl_course 
         ON mdl_course.id = c.instanceid
```

When `mdl_user` or another database change (deleted / updated / inserted) how `compare_moodle` can be synchronized? I think use trigger but don't know how.

Comment: This part is quite confusing to me *When mdl_user or another database change*. Do you mean the other tables.  example you want to the sync the values in `compare_moodle` when `mdl_course` table got changed

Comment: If above query is the  only source of compare_moodle data then just drop this table and create compare_moodle view instead.

Comment: My mean is after database compare_moodle be created, when I delete a course in mdl_course or delete a user in mdl_user,  database compare_moodle be changed. ( less user/course)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) in place of a table for the purpose you present. You'd do that like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW compare_moodle AS
 SELECT mdl_user.id AS userid, 
        mdl_user.username, 
        mdl_user.firstname, 
        mdl_user.lastname, 
        mdl_course.id AS courseid, 
        mdl_course.fullname AS coursename 
   FROM mdl_user 
   JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra    ON mdl_user.id = ra.userid 
   JOIN mdl_role r                 ON ra.roleid = r.id 
                                  AND r.id = 5 
   JOIN mdl_context c              ON ra.contextid = c.id 
   JOIN mdl_course                 ON mdl_course.id = c.instanceid;
```

This gives you a virtual table that is always transactionally up to date with your source tables. SQL best practice teaches us that this approach, without data redundancy, is the best way to do what you want.

The problem, of course, is performance. If you use this `compare_moodle` view a lot you may have slowdowns. Correct indexing of your tables can practically eliminate those slowdowns.   I suggest you get your application working with a view, and then figure out whether you have a performance problem.

What you asked for in your question is a so-called [*materialized view*](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) -- a view represented by an actual table.  In some makes and models of DBMS you can give a command like `CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...` and the DBMS does all the work.  But, MySQL doesn't offer that.

There are various MySQLish approaches to managing materialized views. See here for more information.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/best-way-to-create-a-materialized-view-in-mysql But this approach is a big hassle, and a maintenance headache compared to using an ordinary view.